# How to Fix Windows Exolorer alwas open folder in new window?

Tags: windows-explorer

This is not just question, this is answer:
Very simple.
In CMD as admin type:  regsvr32.exe "%Programfiles%\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
CMD will display message, that is fix succeeded !!1
DONE !

Comment: Please don't do this. While asking and answering your own question is fine (great even), please post your answers as _answers_ and not as part of the question. Just write your question out (not just the title) and then post your solution as an answer.

Comment: The answer in a question format doesn't fit, and I think that "answer" doesn't actually solve the issue of Explorer opening a new window . . .

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 98:**

[image: Visual instructions]

In Windows Explorer go to "View", "Folder Options", "Settings", click "Open each folder in the same window", and then click "OK".

**Windows XP:**

[image: Visual instructions]

In Windows Explorer go to "Tools", "Folder Options", "Open each folder in the same window", click "Apply", and finally click "OK".

**Windows 7:**

[image: Visual Instructions]

In Windows Explorer go to "Organize", "Folder and search options", click "Open each folder in the same window", click "Apply", and finally click "OK".

**Windows 8:**

[image: Visual instructions]

In Windows Explorer go to "View", "Options", "Change folder and search options", click "Open each folder in the same window", click "Apply", and finally click "OK".